# Pasting HTML or Markdown lists preserving indentation

Tags: html, list, text, import, markdown

I need a way to paste Markdown or Google Docs content that is in a list and have the content come out as indented text.

I don't care whether it's an ordered list or unordered list, and I don't care if I'm pasting it into plain text or a spreadsheet.  I don't even care if the underlying content is in Markdown or HTML.  I just want a way to copy indented lists that were created in a WYSIWYG editor and paste them into something that retains the indentation without bringing over the underlying HTML or Markdown or whatever runs the WYSIWYG system.

Example: say I have this list.

```
<ol>
<li>Main Heading
<ul>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
</ul>
<li>Secondary Heading
<ul>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
</ul> 
</ol>
```

It appears as:

1. Main Heading

   - List item 1
   - List item 2
2. Secondary Heading

   - List item 1
   - List item 2

I want to be able to select the list, copy it with Command+C, and paste it into either (a) a spreadsheet where the destination column represents the level of indentation, so that column A is unindented, column B is indented one level, etc., or (b) a plain text document where the indentation is represented as tabs or spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with HTML. HTML does not include any text formatting, it is plain text which has been styled with CSS. Even if you did not write the CSS for the list yourself, it is still styled with CSS using the default CSS properties for the element.

Styling and formatting are completely different, when you copy and paste some text, you are copying the text and the formatting, the CSS styling will be ignored.

Comment: Right.  And there is no way to simply convert styling into formatting?

Comment: Not with HTML and CSS.

Comment: And, correct me if I'm wrong, but the indented lists in things like Microsoft Word and Google Docs work with underlying HTML/CSS, right?

Comment: Google Docs uses HTML on their website, but their web application is written in Java and JavaScript. Microsoft Word is written in C++ and has no HTML. There is a Web version of Microsoft office that uses HTML, but that works in the same way as Google Docs.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In plain text (and sometimes in WYSIWYG editors), indentation is accomplished with spaces and tabs. When you copy from one to another, the spaces and tabs get copied with the rest of the text. In HTML, indentation is accomplished with CSS. There are no spaces and tabs to get copied.

Comment: @Waylan, could you name some WYSIWYG editors that use spaces and tabs?

Comment: MS Word and Google Docs both do if you use spaces and tabs. I was trying to be complete. In WYSIWYG editors, you can either use the provided tools to indent the margin, or you can use spaces and tabs to indent. The former will not necessarily get indented on a copy/paste to plain text, whereas the later will.

Comment: And I should add that if you are using the built-in list tool, then its true, WYSIWYG editors will not be using spaces and tabs (unless you are like my boss who refuses to learn how the tools work and is constantly adding tabs to the beginning of lines where they don't belong...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possibly software dependant. It can be done in Sublime Text Editor using CTRL+SHIFT+V, but in most other programs this command removes the formatting and pastes as plain text.

Comment: In my experience with Sublime Text, Command+Shift+V will paste code and other things that have indentation "hard-coded" in correctly, but still doesn't indent HTML lists.  It seems like this should be simple, since you can so clearly see the indentation, but I have had no luck at all so far.